# How do I use spring mongo data to query based on the position of an element in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have a mongo collection "test" which contains elements like so (with the nodes array being a set and meaningful order):

```
        "test" : {
        "superiorID" : 1, 
        "nodes" : [
            {
                "subID" : 2
            }, 
            {
                "subID" : 1
            }, 
            {
                "subID" : 3
            }
         ]
        }
```

or

```
        "test" : {
        "superiorID" : 4, 
        "nodes" : [
            {
                "subID" : 2
            }, 
            {
                "subID" : 1
            }, 
            {
                "subID" : 3
            }
         ]
        }
```

I am using spring Criteria to try and build a mongo query which will return to me all elements where the '**subID**' equals a user input id '***inputID***' AND the '**superiorID**' position is NOT before the '***inputID***' (if the superior id is even in the sub ids which is not required).

So for example, if my user input was 3 I would NOT want to pull the first document but I WOULD want to pull the second document (first has a superior that exists in the nodes BEFORE the userInput node   second's superior id is not equal to the user input).

I know that the $indexOfArray function exists but I don't know how to translate this to Criteria.

Comment: May be I'm not understanding this correctly.  Something like `db.collection_name.find({"nodes.subID":3, "superiorID":{"$gt":3}})` should work for you. Can you add the code to the post that you have tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result you are looking for through the aggregation framework. I've made a speude query for you to show what you should be looking for. This returns
showMe = false for doc1 and showMe = true for doc2, which you could obiously match for. You do not need 2 project phases for this query, I only did that to make a working query which is also easy-ish to read. This will not be a very fast query. If you want fast queries you might want to rethink your data structure.

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
{ "$project": 
    {
      "superiorIndex":  {"$indexOfArray" : [ "$nodes.subID","$superiorID" ]},
      "inputIndex":  {"$indexOfArray" : [ "$nodes.subID",3 ]},
    }
},
{ "$project": 
    {
      "showMe" : 
      { 
            $cond: 
            { 
                if: { $eq: [ "$superiorIndex", -1 ] }, 
                then: true, 
                else: {$gt:[ "$superiorIndex","$inputIndex"]}
            } 
      }
    }
}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

db.collection.find({nodes.2.subID:2}) that query will lookup 2th element subid from nodes field.